# How to resolve windows installer error The installer was interrupted error

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, orca

i have create windows application and i create a setup file for this project.If i run the .msi file it is working and installation was fine .But,when i set orca settings and run the application i got Installation Error Screen.

**Error:**

```
  The installer was interrupted before <MyApp> could be installed.
  You need to restart the installer to try again.
```

I search for this error in web but i did not get resolve so, finally i post this error in this site.please help me how to resolve this error .

**Note :**
    If i run any msi package file(which is created orca file) does not run in my system only.with out orca settings it is installed correctly..

Comment: If you're talking about the [Orca tool from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905), it's a general purpose editor for MSIs. As such, it can do just about *anything* to an MSI. We don't know *what* you've done with it. As a guess, have you used it to generate a transform (`.mst`) file? (We'd still need more information though)

Comment: Hi thank you for your response,yes i used orca(microsoft tool) settings for getting database instances..if i run this same file in other machine it is working fine. system configuration(my machine and other machine) same.

Comment: I have crate log file please see this link  http://osbornecharles.com/log2.txt

Comment: All of the errors seem to be around the same thing - you've modified some text or other parts of one or more forms, and now the text doesn't fit on the forms.

Comment: But it is working on other machine,not working only in my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that RunSQLList custom action fails. My bet is that there are some SQL related problems on your machine.

Comment: Yes you are right Ciprian ,but how can i resolve this error.Is ther any solution please help me.

Comment: You cannot solve this from the MSI side. Debug SQL on your machine. You said that it works on other computers. What's changed on your machine?

Answer (score 3):

Installing IIS6 Compatibility Tools fixed this for me.

(Note: This is in the year 2017, I built a "hello world" wen application in Visual Studio 2015, added a Web Deployment Project, transferred it to another machine, and this error happens - installing software that was written in 2002 and become obsolete in 2008 fixes the problem)

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should do is, install with logging,

- open an elevated cmd
- msiexec /i  /l*vx setup.log

Then the log to find error codes, normally before the Fatal Error that stops the installer there is a line with error code, in my experience I found the following lines:

> Action WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE returned actual error code **1603**
>
> Closing MSIHANDLE(11)
>
> WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE. Return value 3.
>
> Doing Action: FatalErrorForm.

Finally google that error code, in my case it was ISS 6 Compatibility Role that needed to be added on the server. After adding it the msi installed without errors.

Answer (score 0):

My fix:

When I start Total Commander as regular user, and then start the MSI, it gives an error.

When I start Total Commander as admin, and then start the MSI, it does not give an error.